# Internet Explorer - JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer

Why Internet Explorer behave differently in debugging enabled mode than debugging disabled mode?

a particular java script code works fine when the Internet Explorer runs in debug enable mode

but when the debugging disabled it fails

is there any solution to this kind of java script issue?

Comment: Can you add the line/chunk of code which is failing to your question?  Are you by any chance using `console.log` or something similar?

Comment: Which code is failing?  Please post it

Comment: I think there can be some speed related issues, this is very actual when asynchronous ajax calls are used

Comment: yes console.log("onHandshake " + status);

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can happen if you have asynchronous functions that normally cause race conditions, but in the case of debug mode they do not. We'd need to see some actual code to be able to find the exact cause, but that seems the most likely to me.